# Facebook Share Dialog with URL Redirection not working

Tags: facebook

I'd like to show a share dialog using URL Redirection as described here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

The example they provide is the following : https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=145634995501895&display=popup&href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2F&redirect_uri=https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

I tried to achieve the same with a custom page I created (with og meta tags), here is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title> 
    <meta name="description" content="Page description. No longer than 155 characters." />

    <!-- Twitter Card data --> 
    <meta name="twitter:card" value="summary">

    <!-- Open Graph data --> 
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="762471050442760" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Facebook Developers" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Documentation for building software with Facebook - APIs, SDKs and Services" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/y6/r/YQEGe6GxI_M.png" />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Learn how to integrate with Facebook&#039;s APIs and developer tools to drive growth and engagement to your app, website or content." />
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This page is stored at this location (fake location here) -> www.mysite.com/test.html

Now I try to use the following link to share : https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=MY_APP_ID&display=popup&href=www.mysite.com/test.html&redirect_uri=www.mysite.com

But I don't get the same result as the example they provide. Instead I get some image and description from another website (not at all the one I created with og meta tags).

How can I solve that and customize my share dialog ?

Thanks

Comment: You are saying that your og:url is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/. Use your url instead and it will work better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a cache problem. I managed to refresh this by going to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ with the following Input URL www.mysite.com/test.html